# approaching dynamic programing for problem

Tags: dynamic-programming

I want to find a solution to a problem that asked before.
in the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43435799/path-with-the-minimum-number-of-alterations-in-graph-with-colored-edgest

> I have a directed graph with colored edges (red & blue) that may contain cycles. The question is to write an algorithm given two vertices (s,t) that finds the path with the minimal number of color changes between s and t (if such path exists).
> $

suggesting a reduction to solve the problem.

I want to find an optimal structure for the problem by:
$opt(v) = \min_{u \in In(v)}(opt(u) + f(u,v))$

$f(u,v)$ define:

$f(u,v) = \begin{cases}  1, & \text{the color of (u,v) same as the color that appears more}, \\
-1, & \text{the color of (u,v) the color different from the color that appears more}.\\
1, & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$

the problem with that formula is that the optimum of the neighbors, not gratitude the optimum solution for  $v$ because considering v that have 1 neighbor with a blue edge that has a path with the same blue and red edges and another path with 1 more red edge than my structure return 1 however there is a path with 0 alterations.

then I thinking to save for all the vertices 3 paths, optimum path most optimum path with more blue and path with more red but its seem to complicated to build a formula with that filed.

Comment: Hint: I can think of 2 ways to solve this. (1) $opt(v)$ remembers the optimal solution per vertex, but is this enough information to build solutions to larger subproblems? Maybe you need to instead remember the optimal solution per _____. (2) Transform the graph somehow.

Comment: @j_random_hacker the assignment publisher note that we not allowed to transform the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is easily solved if you:

- transform the input graph $G=(V,E)$ by either creating $n-1$  "levels", where each level is a copy of $G$ and edges go from one level to the next; or
- consider the line graph $G'$ of $G$ instead (so that edges in $G$ become vertices in $G'$, and two vertices in $G'$ are adjacent if the corresponding edges in $G$ share an endpoint); or
- For each color $c \in \{red, blue\}$, identify the maximal components $C$ of $G$ such that connectivity within $C$ is preserved using only edges of color $c$.

If you insist in using a dynamic programming algorithm, then the problem can be solved in $O(m)$ time using a Dijkstra-like algorithm.
Let's start with some definitions:

Given a color $c \in \{red, blue\}$, define a $c$-ending path as a simple path $P$ such that either 1) $P$ is empty, or 2) $P$ ends with an edge of color $c$.

Given a path $P$, let $\ell(P)$ be the number of color changes encountered when traversing $P$.
We will say a path $P$ from $s$ to $v$ is a shortest $c$-ending path if there exist no other $c$-ending path $P'$ such that $\ell(P') < \ell(P)$.

We will call $\eta(v,c)$ the value of $\ell(P)$, where $P$ is a shortest $c$-ending path from $s$ to $v$.

According to the above definitions $\eta(s, red) = \eta(s, blue) = 0$.
Moreover, the following suboptimality property holds:

**Claim:** Let $P$ be any shortest $c$-ending path from $s$ to $v$, let $u \in P$.
The subpath $P[s:u]$ of $P$ going from $s$ to $u$ is a shortest $c'$-ending path where $c'$ is the color of the incoming edge in $u$ (if $u=s$ then $c'$ is any color).

**Proof:**
Assume that $u \neq v$, otherwise the claim is trivial.
Let $c''$ be the color of the edge leaving $u$ in $P$.

Suppose towards a contradiction that $P[s:u]$ is not a shortest $c'$-ending path.
Let $P'$ be a shortest $c'$-ending path from $s$ to $u$, and notice that $Q = P' \circ P[u:v]$ is a (not necessarily simple) path from $s$ to $v$.
$Q$ ends with an edge of color $c$ and we have:
$$
\ell(P) = \ell(P[s:u]) + 1_{c' \neq c''} + \ell(P[u:v])
> \ell(P') + 1_{c' \neq c''} + \ell(P[u:v])
= \ell(Q),
$$
contradicting the fact that $P$ is a shortest $c$-ending path. $\square$

For each node $v$ we will maintain two upper bound $\tilde{\eta}(v, red)$ and $\tilde{\eta}(v, blue)$ on $\eta(v, red)$ and $\eta(v, blue)$, respectively. Initially $\tilde{\eta}(s, red)=\tilde{\eta}(s, blue)=\eta(s, red) = \eta(s, blue) = 0$ while, for $v \neq s$, $\tilde{\eta}(s, red)=\tilde{\eta}(s, blue) = +\infty$.

Finally, we will maintain a priority queue $Q$ in which keys are pairs $(v,c)$ where $v$ is an unmarked vertex and $c$ is a color, and the corresponding priority will be $\tilde{\eta}(v, c)$. Initially all pairs $(v,c)$ are in the queue.

The algorithm proceeds as follows: while $Q$ is not empty, extract $(u,c)$ from $Q$; for each edge $e=(u,v) \in E$ let $c'$ be the color of $e$ and set $\tilde{\eta}(v, c) = \min\{\tilde{\eta}(v, c), \tilde{\eta}(u, c) + 1_{c \neq c'} \}$ (thus possibly updating the priority of $(v,c)$, if such a pair is in $Q$).

It is clear by construction that all values $\tilde{\eta}(v, c)$ are upper bounds to $\eta(v,c)$ as claimed. We now prove that, when the pair $(v,c)$ is extracted from $Q$, $\tilde{\eta}(v, c)$ is also a lower bound to $\eta(v,c)$, thus proving that $\tilde{\eta}(v, c) = \eta(v,c)$.

**Claim:** When $i$-th pair $(v_i,c_i)$ is extracted from $Q$, $\tilde{\eta}(v, c) \le \eta(v,c)$.

**Proof**:
Let $i$ be the smallest value such that, when $(v_i, c_i)$ is extracted from $Q$ we have $\tilde{\eta}(v_i, c_i) > \eta(v_i,c_i)$.

Since the values $\tilde{\eta}(v_i, c_i)$ never decrease during the execution of the algorithm and cannot become negative we know that $v_i \neq s$.
Let $P$ be a shortest $c_i$-ending path from $s$ to $v_i$ and consider the last vertex $x$ such that the incoming edge in $x$ in $P$ has color $c_x$ (if $x=s$ let $c_x$ be any color) and $x=v_j$ and $c_x=c_j$ for some $j<i$ (notice such a vertex always exists since the above conditions are satisfied for $x=s$).
Let $y$ be the vertex following $x$ in $P$ and $c_y$ be the color of the incoming edge.

Since $(v_i, c_i)$ was extracted instead of $(y, c_y)$ we must have:
$$
\tilde\eta(v_i, c_i) \le \tilde\eta(y, c_y)
$$

Moreover, since $(x, c_x)$ was already extracted from $q$ we have:
$$
\tilde\eta(y, c_y) \le \tilde\eta(x, c_x) + 1_{c_x \neq x_y} = \eta(x, c_x) + 1_{c_x \neq x_y}
$$

And, by suboptimality:
$$
\eta(x, c_x) + 1_{c_x \neq x_y} = 
\eta(y, c_y) \le \eta(v_i,c_i),
$$
which is a contradiction $\square$.

The sought quantity is then $\min\{\tilde\eta(t,red), \tilde\eta(t,blue) \}$.

Finally, notice that the the priority can only decrease in $Q$, that the priority of the extracted pairs is monotonically increasing, and that the only possible values of the priorities are $\{0, 1, \dots, n\} \cup \{ +\infty \}$. Therefore it is possible to implement a priority $Q$ that requires $O(n+m) = O(m)$ time to perform all the required $O(n)$ insertions and $O(m)$ priority updates.